# Getting more space on Wubi

Tags: partitioning, wubi, windows-7, mount, disk-usage

First and foremost, note that I'm a complete noob to Linux, so please bear with my confuzzled rambling.

I've recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS via Wubi (18GB installation on the C: drive) on an AMD 64-bit Windows 7 system, and love it. However, I've just discovered that I'm running out of space on the disc; according to system monitor, I'm using 16.2 / 16.8 GiB on ext3 /dev/loop3 (the Ubuntu installation), while I've got more than 400 GBs left on fuseblk /dev/sda3 (/host/). I'd like to know how to re-mount Wubi from ext3 /dev/loop0 to /dev/sda3 and take advantage of the space there - I'm searching, but I have absolutely no idea how to do so.

Results of df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/loop0       17G   17G  551M  97% /
udev            1.8G   12K  1.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           741M  868K  740M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  332K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda3       582G  166G  417G  29% /host
```

Results of sudo losetup -a:

```
/dev/loop0: [0803]:4714 (/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk)
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have 17GB available to your Wubi install. This should be enough to use Wubi because you can always store your personal data on the Windows `/host`. This is recommended anyway because:

1. It's safer on the `/host` - not stored in a virtual drive that is a single file (`root.disk`) that is subject to corruption if Ubuntu freezes and you could lose everything on it.
2. You have plenty of room on `/host`
3. Most of the type of data that takes space e.g. photos, music, video, you'd want available to Windows and it's not easily available if it's stuck on the `root.disk` (without a tool like [ext2read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/))

The only reason you might need more space is if you're compiling kernels or other software.

You could also consider what your needs are. If you want a robust long term Ubuntu install, Wubi probably isn't it.

Other ways to make space:

1. Remove all but the last two kernels. You can use this script for that: [clean_kernel.sh](https://raw.github.com/bcbc/utilities/master/clean_kernel.sh). Just download it with `wget https://raw.github.com/bcbc/utilities/master/clean_kernel.sh` and run `bash clean_kernel.sh`
2. Clean up unneeded packages: `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean`
3. Look for other junk by running the disk usage analyzer (`baobab`). Go to settings before running and uncheck the `/host` or it will search the whole Windows partition. Look for large files in `/home` you can delete or move to `host`

Of course you can resize the Wubi install, but - as mentioned - a normal dual boot is better for long term.

Answer (score 0):

IMO if you are wanting to keep Ubuntu you are best off doing a standard installation.

It is possible te resize the wubi disk, but is is a little more time consuming and difficult.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_resize_the_virtual_disks.3F